# Vue.js: initialize the data object with data from the page or from v-text directive

Tags: vue.js

So I'm just starting to play with Vue.js and I would like to know if there is a nice way to initialize the **data** object with html tags content from the page.

Basically I have a page that displays information and I would like to turn it into a tiny Vue application to avoid having a separated edit page.
So I added the form with 2 way binding which submits the values via ajax.

The thing is I really want to avoid Flash Of Uncompiled Content, but then I feel like I have to duplicate all my data, once in the html tag, once in the data object.

```
<div id="app">
  <span v-text="prop1">This is filled by the backend</span>
  <input v-model="prop1" type="text" v-cloak />
</div>

<script>
new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {prop1: "This is filled by the backend..again"}   // << Can I avoid this?
});
</script>
```

Could I tell Vue to get the data from the html tags since it's already there?

Thanks!

Comment: Instead of having backend dynamically generate scripts, you can put the initial json serialized data into a prop of a vue component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [props](http://vuejs.org/api/#props)

Your html element would look something like 
`<custom-element dataToPass="dataFromHtml"></custom-element>`.
Then you can access it in your vue instance via `this.dataToPass`.

Have a read through the documentation, there is a difference if you pass a string or an expression (from another vue instance for example).

In your example:

```
<div id="app">
      <span prop1="{ backendVariable}" v-text="prop1"></span>
      <input v-model="prop1" type="text" v-cloak />
</div>

<script>
    new Vue({
        el: "#app",
        props: ['prop1']
    });
</script>
```

```